# How can i create a common ViewModel with a varying Resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, internationalization, resource-files

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{   
   [Display(Name = "One_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Resource1))]
   public string One { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Two_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Resource1))]
   public string Two { get; set; }
}
```

Which is used on **page 1**, and works great (e.g pulls back the resource) when i do stuff like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.One)
```

But i also want to use this ViewModel on **page 2**, but i wan't to point the properties to a different resource file (e.g `Resources.User.Resource2`).

I don't want to have to dupe the class, but i'd be open to some OO trick.

The problem is that the attribute arguments must be strings, constants, `typeof` or array expressions.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: where is @Darin Dimitrov when i need him. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it does seem like MVC doesn't support such a scenario. You can provide your own ResourceType class but it must have static properties (such as `public static string One_Name` and `public static string Two_Name` in your example) that return the display strings, and there is no elegant way to make it do what you want.

But since `Html.LabelFor` doesn't do anything particularly earth-shattering, you could easily do without in a view. Just write your own `<label>` element and get the localized string directly, which is as easy as calling `ResourceManager.GetString`. You could still use `Html.LabelFor` in most cases and only resort to writing your own labels in the (hopefully rare) cases where a certain view does need to vary the display text.